# Why vim disallows globbing with :e command?

Tags: vim, vi

I use buffers as "tabs" in Vim, and open new files using `:e[dit]` command. Why can't I use globbing with `:e` command?

```
:e some_dir/*
E77: Too many file names
```

Comment: I’ve always wondered why you can’t even do this with `:tab split`...

Comment: `:e some_dir/*` is ambiguous: Vim can edit a file or list the content of a directory. `:e some_dir/*.js` or `:e some_dir/<tab>` are perfectly fine, though.

Comment: hm, `:e some_dir/*.js` gives me same `E77: Too many file names`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `:n` instead:

```
:n some_dir/*
```

Comment: if anybody is wondering :n is :next

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use globbing with `:edit` and other commands; however, there must be a *single, unique result* of the glob, because the `:edit` command only takes a single file. (How else should it display multiple matches in the single current window?)

If you want to edit multiple files sequentially, you can use `:args` or `:argadd` instead. Note that the `:split` command does not take multiple files, neither (probably because of the risk that many matches will inadvertently cause an impractically large number of window splits), but you could write your own `:Split` command that provides this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You should use :args or :argadd instead.

```
:args src/*
:tab all
```

First command loads all files from src/ folder to buffers and second command puts each buffer then into separate tabs.

:help arglist will give more information